# Is it possible to disable menu items in custom menus?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I want to disable and enable menu items (layout.operator) in my custom menu, the disabled ones should be displayed greyed. I managed to disable the whole menu with layout.enabled = False, but I failed to disable a single menu item.

Something similar what I want to achieve can be seen in the "Ui Menu" Python template with the entry "Hello world!", but this is a layout.label and not a layout.operator. Before I use this approach as workaround I'd like to know if there is a more easy way to dis- or enable single menu items.

Comment: You can implement [operator.poll](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=operator.poll#bpy.types.Operator.poll) for your own operators. If the operators poll method returns false the operator will automatically be disabled in the UI.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Will you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already said by pink vertex and Jerryno, a `poll()` classmethod should be added to the operator you add to the custom menu. The disabling (graying out) will be managed by Blender automatically:

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Simple Operator"
    bl_idname = "wm.simple_operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return len(context.selected_objects) % 2 == 0

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Simple Operator executed.")
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SimpleOperator2(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Simple Operator 2"
    bl_idname = "wm.simple_operator2"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.object is not None and
                context.object.type == 'CAMERA')

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Simple Operator 2 executed.")
        return {'FINISHED'}


class SimpleCustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Simple Custom Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_simple_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.label("Enabled, if even number of objects selected", icon='INFO')
        layout.operator("wm.simple_operator")
        layout.separator()
        layout.label("Enabled, if active object is a camera", icon='INFO')
        layout.operator("wm.simple_operator2")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # The menu can also be called from scripts
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=SimpleCustomMenu.bl_idname)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want specific GUI elements to be disabled, set corresponding `row.enable` or `column.enable` to False:

```
row = layout.row()
row.operator("something")
# maybe more row stuff here
row.enable = False
```

If you want this build in into the operator itself, include the [poll](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=operator.poll#bpy.types.Operator.poll) method. This will grey it in the UI and also be safe when the user calls the operator from search (spacebar) for example!

Comment: I am not sure how these row commands could be integrated into CoDEmanX's SimpleCustomMenu above or into Blender's "Ui Menu" template I am derivating from. Sounds more they could be used in panels, but I am not familar with these yet. But anyway, I am happy with my new poll() method!